# Using useState to update style of the current object that is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have Accordion styling for cardviews in my page. When the user clicks on a card the cards color should change along with its font color. Currently to do this I'm using setState and conditional rendering to change the colors of a card on click which is working, but it's changing the color for all my cards, even the ones that are not clicked. How do I make it so it only changes it for the current card that is clicked.

Code:

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
<div className="row">
  {items &&
    items.map((item) => (
      <div className="col-md-6 faqpadding">
        <Accordion
          className="cardHeight"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: clicked ? "#fff" : "#0e2043",
            boxShadow: "0px 4px 22px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17)",
            border: "1px solid #919191",
            color: clicked ? "#0e2043" : "#E3AB50",
            padding: "20px",
          }}
        >
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
            id="panel1a-header"
            onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}
          >
            <Typography
              className={classes.heading}
              style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
            >
              {item.Title}
            </Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>{item.Content}</Typography>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-nash-ps8m7?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Please try to create a minimum code to reproduce an issue. I suggest that you replace your code with li element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single state variable that has a type of `boolean` to try and track multiple items, that's never going to work.

You could have an `array` of items that should have the `clicked` state, say by storing their index or some unique id e.g.

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([])
```

Then on click, add (or remove) from the array:

```
onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
// or
onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}
```

```
const handleClick = (index) => {
   if(clicked.includes(index)) {
       // remove from 'clicked' array
   } else {
       // add to 'clicked' array
   }
}
```

Then to set your styles, it would be something like:

```
backgroundColor: clicked.includes(index) ? "#fff" : "#0e2043",
```

Where `index` is the second argument of the `map` callback, or better still use the *id* of the item if there is one.

```
backgroundColor: clicked.includes(item.id) ? "#fff" : "#0e2043",
```

Comment: As far as I understood, OP only wants the current card to be different. For that purpose it would be sufficient to only store the currently active item.

Comment: yea fair point, if they need one item at a time, store the single id, or if multiple items can be selected, store the ids in an array

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same state to change the style conditionally, hence when state changes the style is applied to both the cards.
To fix this you can create a card component and move all your text content to it through props and then use the same component twice.
I tried doing this and here's the link to the final code-  https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-rgb-us349

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Accordion from "@material-ui/core/Accordion";
import AccordionSummary from "@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary";
import AccordionDetails from "@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
  }
}));

const CARD_ONE = 1;
const CARD_TWO = 2;
const CARD_DEFAULT = -1;

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [clickedCard, setClickedCard] = useState(CARD_DEFAULT);
  console.log(clickedCard);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-wESLQ85D6gbsF459vf1CiZ2+rr+CsxRY0RpiF1tLlQpDnAgg6rwdsUF1+Ics2bni"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
      </Head>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div style={{ minHeight: "100vh", backgroundColor: "#0e2043" }}>
          <div className="container" style={{ paddingTop: "80px" }}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-6 faqpadding">
                <Accordion
                  className="cardHeight"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor:
                      clickedCard === CARD_ONE ? "#fff" : "#0e2043",
                    boxShadow: "0px 4px 22px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17)",
                    border: "1px solid #919191",
                    color: clickedCard === CARD_ONE ? "#0e2043" : "#E3AB50",
                    padding: "20px"
                  }}
                >
                  <AccordionSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                    onClick={() => setClickedCard(CARD_ONE)}
                  >
                    <Typography
                      className={classes.heading}
                      style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                    >
                      WHAT IS CITIZENSHIP-BY-INVESTMENT?
                    </Typography>
                  </AccordionSummary>
                  <AccordionDetails>
                    <Typography>
                      Citizenship-by-Investment (“CBI”) schemes offers instant
                      passport to foreigners to make a a lump sum donation to
                      the state or through buying a qualified real estate. The
                      concept of CBI was first born in St Kitts and Nevis in
                      1984.
                    </Typography>
                  </AccordionDetails>
                </Accordion>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 faqpadding">
                <Accordion
                  className="cardHeight"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor:
                      clickedCard === CARD_TWO ? "#fff" : "#0e2043",
                    boxShadow: "0px 4px 22px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17)",
                    border: "1px solid #919191",
                    color: clickedCard === CARD_TWO ? "#0e2043" : "#E3AB50",
                    padding: "20px"
                  }}
                >
                  <AccordionSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                    onClick={() => setClickedCard(CARD_TWO)}
                  >
                    <Typography
                      className={classes.heading}
                      style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                    >
                      WHICH IS THE PROGRAM THAT GETS ME INTO MOST COUNTRIES?
                    </Typography>
                  </AccordionSummary>
                  <AccordionDetails>
                    <Typography>
                      Citizenship-by-Investment (“CBI”) schemes offers instant
                      passport to foreigners to make a a lump sum donation to
                      the state or through buying a qualified real estate. The
                      concept of CBI was first born in St Kitts and Nevis in
                      1984.
                    </Typography>
                  </AccordionDetails>
                </Accordion>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-issu-12uw1)